# Flag marked helpful, but nothing changed

Tags: support, review-queues, flags, scope

I flagged a question as off-topic (as it asked for references, not to fix a problem), and it has been marked as helpful, but nothing seems to have changed. At worst I thought the question would be put on hold, and more than likely would be deleted - but no notice has been put on the question, and no edits have been made to it either.

The question is [Preparing to Zend PHP Certification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119568/preparing-to-zend-php-certification) (sic).

Is this a common occurrence? It's just not what I would expect to happen to a *helpful* flag.

**As a secondary question**, but related to this; where can I find the review details for my flags? I see others have posted links to reviews they've raised the flags of before. I'm talking about a page like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5673458). I've clicked on almost everything on my flag summary page, but I can't see the details.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking about WRT "review summary" - might want to spin off a separate question about that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your flag was marked as helpful because someone with [closing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) agreed with it. As soon as they cast an actual close *vote*, your flag is marked "Helpful".

The post wasn't closed because it took 5 such votes to close a post, meaning 4 additional people with closing privileges would have needed to agree with the first voter.

(Policy has changed since the question was originally asked; it now takes only 3 such votes to close the post.)

I went ahead and closed it, as I also agree that it's a pretty poor question as it stands.