# Day Asked not displaying correctly on MSO

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, meta

I just updated [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272717/flag-marked-helpful-but-nothing-changed) I asked yesterday on MSO (almost 24 hours ago), but the page is trying to tell me that it was asked *today*, which is clearly wrong.

This looks like a bug to me. Is it a known issue?

Comment: Should change in about 2 minutes when it passes the 24 hour mark.

Comment: Does it not work on UTC days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page will have the timestamp of the question in the markup of the page, in UTC.

Javascript goes through these timestamps and renders them in *relative time*, where < 24 hours is indeed considered today.