# Where can I find the review details for my flags?

Tags: support, review-queues, flags, flag-history

I had put this question as a secondary in [Flag Marked Helpful, But Nothing Changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272717/flag-marked-helpful-but-nothing-changed), but I was advised to make this a separate question.

Where can I find the review details for my flags? I see others have posted links to reviews they've raised the flags of before. I've clicked on almost everything on my flag summary page, but I can't see the details.

I'm talking about the page like [this low quality post review details](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5673458), or [this suggested edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5937099) but for posts I flag.

I guess you need to know the review ID, but it's not obvious where I can find it!

Comment: Referring to your current revision: Are you meaning the ID Lostsock refers to in their answer? Because that is _post_ ID, not review. If you look at the url Lostsock uses, it's the url to the answer in the LQP queue that you linked to. You can find that by clicking the "share" link under the post. Lostsock shows you where the id is in that url. Also, if my assumption is correct, you should have posted that as a comment under the answer, not an edit to the question.

Comment: @Kendra If I copy and paste that ID from a post I've flagged (and been found to be helpful) as low quality, to the url of the low quality posts queue (eg https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26248425) you can see that the result is page not found.

Comment: Use the query Lostsock posted. Did you try the query? I just did, and the last three entries listed for the low quality post have the review ID in the "id" column for the LQP queue.

Answer (score 6):

So you're looking to see how users voted in the review queues, to posts that you either flagged or suggested an edit on?

Thanks to @rene's brilliant sql skills, you should be able to find this info [**using this query**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/208490/find-the-reviews-for-a-post)

Just copy/paste the post id from the url and enter it in the box and click run.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12514383/3041194
                           ^^^^^^^^
```

As an example, I just ran the id of that low quality post you linked to which is 12514383.

It turns out that, that answer also made appearances in the first post queue and late answer queue.

Comment: You might want to flesh this out a little bit. The OP seemed to misunderstand what the query did, and I know I was a bit confused as well until I tried it. :) Maybe explain how the query will help find the review?